# Submit an updated manpage

Tags: man, openssh

I found missing information in the manpage for `scp` when using IP6: there is no hint that you have to use slash masked brackets around the IP when using `scp -6`:

```
scp -6 user@\[2001:db8:0:1\]:/tmp/test.file /tmp
```

How can I submit a change to the scp manpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you seek is [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html):

```
COLOPHON        

     This page is part of the openssh (Portable OpenSSH) project.  Informa‐ 
     tion about the project can be found at
     http://www.openssh.com/portable.html.  If you have a bug report for
     this manual page, see http://www.openssh.com/report.html.  This page
     was obtained from the tarball openssh-6.6p1.tar.gz fetched from‐
     http://ftp.eu.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/
     on 2014-07-09.  If you discover any rendering problems in this HTML
     version of the page, or you believe there is a better or more up-to-
     date source for the page, or you have corrections or improvements to
     the information in this COLOPHON (which is not part of the original
     manual page), send a mail to man-pages@man7.org
```

Comment: OK, I added this in the [bugzilla of portable OpenSSH](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2258)

Answer (score 1):

Familiarize yourself with the man language (e.g. learn about it [here](http://liw.fi/manpages/)), gunzip `scp`'s man page (find it with `locate scp.1.gz`) `/usr/share/man/man1/scp.1.gz`, edit it accordingly, save it again at the same location as gz. That's it.

Comment: OK, and how do I publish it to the maintainers?

Comment: @rubo77 argh I misread that, thought that you only want to add something locally, not globally. Well sorry :(!

Comment: Plus `sudo mandb` after `gz` file replacement. P.S. QA was found as top websearch result for stackexchange.com for changing man page description, so IMO answer is useful here. BTW step 1 (learning link) is not necessary for small edits.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to go is: **submit a patch** to the maintainers/makers of the software. If you don't know who they are, you can just submit it to your distribution bug tracker.